# ArcMap layout view missing page rulers and border?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, data-driven-pages, layouts

Sometimes, but not always, when I open an existing .mxd, the rulers and border (and shadow) are missing in layout view. All elements are there otherwise. When this happens, I am unable to export to either .emf or .pdf. I can't discern any rhyme or reason.

These are data driven pages, in case that's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just learned that if I un-select "Use Printer Paper Settings" in the Page and Print Setup menu, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

The problem also has to do with printer selection. My rulers were missing too and the MXD wouldn't export. I noticed that ArcGIS was trying to reference printer drivers we no longer have and as a consequence the paper settings were greyed out. I set the MXD to the new printer in the Page and Print Setup dialog and I was able to set the paper size again, then I checked Use Printer Paper settings. Rulers returned and I was able to export.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my PC and the problem simply solved.